# How to deploy MERN project using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, mern

I use the following project which use webpack
https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter

I want to deploy it (to prod)  i get error

Error: Cannot find module './dist/manifest.json'
This error is coming from https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter/blob/master/index.js

But I dont see the dist folder in the project, why, and how should I build it?

I believe that the Dist folder should be created during the build time (manification etc) **so how should I trigger it**  ?

This is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "mern-starter",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Boilerplate project for building Isomorphic apps using React and Redux",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test PORT=8080 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mern-test node_modules/.bin/nyc node --harmony-proxies node_modules/.bin/ava",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "cover": "nyc npm run test",
    "check-coverage": "nyc check-coverage --statements 100 --branches 100 --functions 100 --lines 100",
    "start": "cross-env BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js",
    "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node index.js",
    "bs": "npm run clean && npm run build && npm run build:server && npm run start:prod",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js",
    "build:server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.server.js",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "slate": "rimraf node_modules && npm install",
    "lint": "eslint client server"
  },
```

I think that the start:prod should trigger it in the webpack but
its not happing ...any idea ?

Comment: How are you trying to deply? Are you using `npm run bs` as the documentation suggested?

Comment: @UnholySheep - thanks , no I didnt did it but let me check now and let you know ... btw can I simulate is somehow locally ? I mean run the process which create the dist etc ?

Comment: Well, that's what `npm run bs` is supposed to do (via `npm run build` and `npm run build:server` which it calls).

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks now it build the dist folder :) please write is as an answer and I'll vote up, but there is another issue it seems that when I deploy it run the script of dev "start" script why and how should i tell it to run the prod script ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the exact issue, but I think you need to use either `npm run start:prod` (instead of just `npm run start`) or copy the execution command from the *package.json* file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments and the documentation:

Building the *dist* folder is done either via `npm run bs` or `npm run build && npm run build:server` (which is what `npm run bs` executes).

Starting the production build should be done via `npm run start:prod` (or by copying the commands from the *package.json* file: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node index.js`)

Comment: voted up!any idea direction how to do it ? maybe via command?https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html#start

Comment: @RaynD I don't have any experience with Cloudfoundry, but based on the link you should be able to put either of the two commands in the `command` field of the procfile

Comment: no, just the second one (`npm run start:prod`) should be enough.

Comment: last question,:) maybe you can have a clue, when doing what you suggest npm run start:prod the application is failed to deploy since its looking for dev dependancies  such as webpack and postcss-cssnext how this can happen ? this is dev_dependncies ...any idea suggestion?

Comment: @RaynD If I had to guess, I'd say that the `NODE_ENV` variable doesn't get set when run this way. Using either [`set-env`](http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/set-env.html)  or [Environment Variable Groups](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-7/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#evgroups) might be a solution. But as I said I have no experience with Cloudfoundry, so you might have to find more information somewhere (or open a new question about it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132032/discussion-between-rayn-d-and-unholysheep).

Comment: Thanks but I did it and it not solved the issue.thanks anyway